# Modificar as chaves primárias padrão do Rails pode gerar algum problema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, convenções-de-nome, convenções

Por padrão, o Rails gera o campo id para todas as minhas tabelas e eu gostaria de saber se, futuramente, pode gerar algum erro caso eu mude o nome e o tipo da chave. Pergunto isso pois percebi que o Rails tem algumas convenções de nomenclatura que devem ser seguidas.
Peço desculpas se a pergunta for meio boba, mas estou preocupado com a possibilidade de ter problemas futuramente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar a chave primária para outra coluna:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'nomecoluna'
end
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html